# Keep some local file history in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse does have a list of local history for each file, with all the changes made, each time one saves the file. The list is kept for a specific period of time, after which older history is deleted.

My question is, can I flag some of the local history files to keep, no to be deleted ever?

The reason being that most changes between history files are not important, one is used to hit **ctrl-s** to save from time to time. But there are times when I know I want to start a big change and I would like to preserve the current version, just in case in half year from now I need to *compare* or *roll back*.

*I know that local history is not meant to be version control, but it is automatic and requires 0 effort from me, no need to checkout or commit.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local history is configured in `Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History`.

You can turn off the limit on the history size completely, but you can't keep just some files longer.

It really is worth investing a bit of time on using one of the version control systems supported by Eclipse.